# What exactly does ALSA's snd_pcm_delay() return?

Tags: linux, audio, delay, latency, alsa

I want to use `snd_pcm_delay()` to query the delay until the sample I am about write to the ALSA buffer are hearable. I expect this value to vary between individual calls. Though, on two system this value is constant. The function returns a value that is always equal to the period size on one platform and on the other platform it is equal to the buffer size (two times the period size in my code).

Is my understanding of `snd_pcm_delay()` wrong? Is it a driver problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delay is proportional to the number of samples in the buffer (the inverse of `snd_pcm_avail()`), plus a time that describes how much time is needed to move samples from the buffer to the speakers. The latter part is driver dependent and might not be implemented.

If the device takes out samples one entire period at a time (some DMA controllers have no better granularity for reporting the current position), then the delay value will appear to stay constant for a time, and then jump by an entire period. And you see that jump only before you have re-filled the buffer.